# Измерить промежуток времени в Qt 4.4

Tags: c++, qt

Использую Qt 4.4. Необходимо измерить время выполнения функции в миллисекундах.
Сейчас сделано так

```
QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
process();
int msec = time.msecsTo( QTime::currentTime() );
if ( msec < 0 )
    msec += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

msec - кол-во миллисекунд которые выполнялась ф-ция process(). Смущает костыль:

```
if ( msec < 0 )
    msec += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Если process() начнет выполняться до полуночи, а закончится после, msec будет примерно минус сутки, поэтому пришлось вставить проверку. В Qt 4.4 QDateTime не хранит микросекунды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам микросекунды то? Используйте `QDateTime` и `QTime` совместно:

```
QDateTime start = QDateTime::currentDateTime();

process(); 

QDateTime finish = QDateTime::currentDateTime();

int secs = finish.secsTo(start);
start.addSecs(secs);
int msecs = finish.time().msecsTo(start.time());

int msecs_duration = secs * 1000 + msecs;
```

Answer (score 1):

А вам действительно необходимо измерять в миллисекундах время больше 24 часов? Если нет, то у QTime есть прекрасные методы:

`QTime t;
 t.start();
 some_lengthy_task();
 qDebug("Time elapsed: %d ms", t.elapsed());`

Предупреждение:

`Note that the counter wraps to zero 24 hours after the last call to start() or restart().`

[Ссылка на doc](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.4.3/qtime.html#start)

Answer (score 0):

А если код выполнялся три дня (то есть пережил два раза полночь)?

Я бы посмотрел на это `QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()` - количество миллисекунд с начала эпохи (с 1970 года).

Comment: ему Qt 4.4 нужен, а эта функция с 4.7 появилась